# Extension property: Function declaration must have a name Unresolved reference: get

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-extension

I use extension function to extend `retrofit2.Response` object:

Snippet:

```
public class ErrorResponse {
    private int code;
    private String message;
    private Response response;
}

import okhttp3.MediaType
import okhttp3.Protocol
import okhttp3.Request
import okhttp3.ResponseBody
import retrofit2.Response

fun Response<*>.errorResponse(): ErrorResponse {
    val errorResponse = ErrorUtils.parseError(this)
    return errorResponse
}
```

And here use:

```
viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
            val response: Response<*> = TransportService.getTraidersList()
            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                finishLoadData()
                val traders: List<Trader> = response.body() as List<Trader>
                traderListLiveData.postValue(traders)
            } else { 
                val errorResponse = response.errorResponse()
                val message = errorResponse.message // here use extension function
                messageLiveData.value = SingleEvent(message)
            }
}
```

Nice. It's work fine.

But I want to use extension properties. I try this:

```
val Response<*>.errorResponse: ErrorResponse {
   get() = ErrorUtils.parseError(this)
}
```

But I get compile error:

```
Function declaration must have a name Unresolved reference: get
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need brackets for properties. It may look like this:

```
val Response<*>.errorResponse: ErrorResponse
   get() = ErrorUtils.parseError(this)
```